# Вывод даты gmdate

Tags: php

Вывод даты

```
gmdate("06.10 10:02", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
gmdate("d.m H:i", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
```

второй вариант рабочий, но мне необходимо, чтобы работал первый,
буду благодарен за решения вопроса

Comment: Укажите в метках язык

Comment: Ну и вопрос смотрите документацию, ваш первый вариант не соответсвует правильному формату, что вы вообще хотите?http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gmdate.php